# abort ui-router transition asynchronously without generating a TransitionRejection log

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to abort a ui-router transition without having an error log entry, i cannot use transition.abort() because i have to wait for a user input ("unsaved changes. continue?") so i return a promise.

```
  $transitions.onExit({exiting: 'main.settings'}, function(transition) {      
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // promise testing
    $timeout(function(){
      // here i need to create a Rejection Object with type = RejectType.ABORTED 
      deferred.reject(false);
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise;
  });
```

If i reject the promise, i get the error log entry, because i don't know, how to create a Rejection with a RejectType.ABORTED in my controller. How can i get access to the Rejection Class?

Or is there any other way, how i can abort a transition asynchronously without creating a error log entry?

Using Angular 1.5.1 and ui-router 1.0.5.

Also asked at https://github.com/ui-router/core/issues/35.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Returning rejected promise or false value in transition hook seems like the most natural way to abort the transition.

However if you don't want to clutter the log with the error messages you need to provide `defaultErrorHandler()` as described here - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#defaulterrorhandler

If you would like to process some specific transitions errors you need to 
provide `onError` hook for this as described here - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onerror

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by defining my own `defaultErrorHandler()`. Now i can prevent  error messages to show up after aborting a transition.

Thanks @ Pavel Bely